# Size of UITableView behaves strange on different screen sizes

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uikit, ios-simulator

I have a UITableView created in a Storyboard, with leading and trailing space -20.0 to superview to make it stretch across the whole screen.

The strange thing is when I now run this on a iPhone 6 (simulator) and in viewDidLoad print:

```
 print("TableView width: \(tableView.frame.width)")
 print("Screen width: \(UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width)")
```

I get

```
TableView width: 600.0
Screen width: 375.0
```

And the same in viewDidAppear gives me:

```
TableView width: 383.0
Screen width: 375.0
```

While doing the exact same thing on a iPhone 6 Plus (also simulator) prints

```
TableView width: 600.0
Screen width: 414.0
```

and

```
TableView width: 414.0
Screen width: 414.0
```

respectively.

Why is the width of the table view different from the screen width in the iPhone 6 case, and not in the 6 Plus case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i ran into this problem, i think it's some kind of bug or a bad feature, to solve this i created the custom cell programmatically, and done some calculations using the screen width and height to place objects and size them properly without using any weird a$$ constraints, **this worked really well for me**, but someone else might have a better solution that suites some and may not some others, consider the (programmatically) approach, i find it good, good luck.

Comment: I ended up making everything programmatically, as I couldn't get it to look right on different screen sizes using Storyboards. I adjusted the size/frame of the TableView in the viewControllers' `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` method, as then I can get the correct screen size from `self.view.frame` .